# Submitting multiple forms via AJAX - sync or async

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a bit of situation where I have multiple forms on the same page that I need submit via ajax by pressing a single "Save" button. I'm doing this by looping through the forms using $.each and then making the ajax request. The ajax requests are supposed to send back a response (errors / success message).

My problem is - would I be making a mistake by using ASYNC requests, as there might be a problem with matching up which output goes to which form ? What do you guys think ?

Comment: Never use synchronous XHR requests.

Comment: What he said ^^^^^^ !

Comment: What am I missing here then ? Would async requests not have a problem with matching which output goes to what form as async requests don't wait on completion.

Comment: Not if you keep a proper order and know what you're sending etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use synchronous XHR requests; there's no valid reason to use them, and it results in terrible user experience.

You don't have to worry about the requests getting mixed up:

```
$('form').each(function() {
    var form = $(this);
    $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(r) {
        // `form` is still the particular form submitted,
        // and `r` will be the results of posting that form.
    });
});
```