# Targeting multiple forms to send via ajax (jquery)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have multiple forms on my page.  When I click the forms submit button, I want to send the form value of only that form through ajax. Here is what I have.  The first form works as its supposed to, the second form actually submits the form.  How can I target each form individually.  I feel I should be using .find() somewhere.

```
 <form id="form1" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="name1" name="value" value="">
    <input type="submit"  id="update_form"  value="Save Changes">
  </form>

 <form id="form2" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="name2" name="value" value="">
    <input type="submit"  id="update_form"  value="Save Changes">
 </form>



<script>
// this is the id of the submit button
$("#update_form").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "approve_test.php",
           data: $(this.form).serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use same id for elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419022/submitting-multiple-forms-via-ajax-sync-or-async

Comment: @Skelly I actually saw that, but he wanted to submit multiple forms with one button. I  have a submit button for each form.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't use same id for multiple elements. Use class instead.
Change your code to this:

```
<form id="form1" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="name1" name="value" value="">
    <input type="submit"  class="update_form"  value="Save Changes"> <!-- changed -->
</form>

<form id="form2" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="name2" name="value" value="">
    <input type="submit"  class="update_form"  value="Save Changes"> <!-- changed -->
</form>

<script>
// this is the class of the submit button
$(".update_form").click(function() { // changed
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "approve_test.php",
           data: $(this).parent().serialize(), // changed
           success: function(data) {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
    });
    return false; // avoid to execute the actual form submission.
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

First, use class in your submit buttons. Be aware that ids are unique (by w3c specs)

Then in your onclick listener, get the form using closest (same as parent but targeting a specific parent; in this case it is the form element). Here is the working code:

```
 <form id="form2" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="name2" name="value" value="">
    <input type="submit"  class="update_form"  value="Save Changes">
 </form>



<script>
// this is the id of the submit button
$(".update_form").click(function() {
    var myform = $(this).closest("form"); //parent form
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "approve_test.php",
           data: myform.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with what you are doing here.

**Multiple elements with the same id:**

From your mark up, it can be seen that both `form1` and `form2` have the same `id` for their respective submit buttons. This is not valid mark up. You should have them set to something such as `form1-submit` and `form2-submit`.

**Identifying the form to be submitted**

In the data attribute of the AJAX request, to identify the form you want to submit, you can use:

`data: $(this).parent().serialize(),`

Now, to avoid code repetition by creating handlers for each of the two buttons, give both your  submit buttons the same class and attach an `onclick` event handler to that class like this:

```
//Submit buttons
<input type="submit" id="submit1" class="submit-buttons" />
<input type="submit" id="submit2" class="submit-buttons" />

//Event handler
$('.submit-buttons').click(function(){
   //Your code here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form method="post" action="form1_process.php" >
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form 1">
</form>

<form method="post" action="form2_process.php" >
    <input type="text" name="name" >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Form 2">
</form>

<script>

    /* get all form and loop */
    $( "form" ).each( function () {

        /* addEventListener onsubmit each form */
        $( this ).bind( "submit", function (event) {

            /* return false */
            event.preventDefault();

            var formHTML = event.target; // formHTML element

            $.ajax({
                method: formHTML.method,
                url: formHTML.action,

                data: $( this ).serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.

                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert(data); // show response from the php script.
                }
            });          

        } );

    });

</script>
```

In server, form1_process.php and form2_process.php

```
<?php

    var_dump($_POST);
```

[Demo](https://jquery-form-multi-submit-preventdefault-ajax--antelove19.repl.co/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var form = $('#form1', '#form2').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "approve_test.php",
    data: form,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data); // show response from the php script.
    }
});
```

Comment: please add some explanation.