# to submit a form among multiple forms using jquery-ajax

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery, multiple-forms

i have multiple forms with same class name

```
<form >
  <input type="hidden" value="<%=ids%>" name="idd">
  <input type="hidden" value="<%=email%>" name="cby">
  <input type="text" class="cmd" name="cm" style="width:300px;" placeholder="comment">
  <input type="submit" value="" style="display:none;">
</form>
  <!-- n number of forms are  generated using while loop-->
<form>
  <input type="hidden" value="<%=ids%>" name="idd">
  <input type="hidden" value="<%=email%>" name="cby">
  <input type="text" class="cmd" name="cm" style="width:300px;" placeholder="comment">
  <input type="submit" value="" style="display:none;">
</form>
```

Then how can i submit a single form among this n number of forms i tried using

```
   $(function () {
          $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                 type: 'post',
                  url: 'addfr.jsp',
                  data: $('form').serialize(),
                  success: function () {
                  location.reload();

                  }
          });
         e.preventDefault();
     });
  });
```

But it is submitting always 1st form among the n-forms.
How can submit a random form among the n-forms.
May any one help me please.

Comment: Same type question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638181/targeting-multiple-forms-to-send-via-ajax-jquery/59319231#59319231

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to reference the form with `this` when you serialize it...

```
$(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'addfr.jsp',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function () {
                location.reload();
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 beat me by half a second, but that seems to be the problem, serializing all the forms everytime the submit event on one of the forms is triggered.

Comment: @adeneo You need to get well greased up to be quick enough on this site, don't you!  As long as they get their answers :)

Comment: `$(this).serialize()` may not not work in `ajax` so you should use a variable for `this reference` and then use it.

Comment: @RohanKumar - there is no new scope, so `this` will work just fine.

Comment: @HarikaChoudaryKanikanti What do you mean by "not working"?  What is actually happening?

Comment: @Archer sorry it's working know. Thanks for your work

Answer (score 1):

Use this keyword. It will submit the form on which the event has been triggered.

why are u using location.reload?

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'addfr.jsp',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function () {
        location.reload();
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 You can try this...

 function submitForm(){
document.formName.action="actionName";
document.formName.submit();
 }


 <form method="post" name="formName" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  ....
 <input type="button" onclick="submitForm()"/>
 <form>
```