# submit two forms within a servlet

Tags: java, javascript, forms, jakarta-ee, servlets

I want to submit two forms within a servlet,success of second form is not compulsory.whether the second submission successful or not first submission should succeed.

first submit

```
out.print("<html>");
out.print("<head>");
out.print("<script language=\"javascript\">
              function autoSubmit(){
              document.form1.submit();}</script>");

out.print("</head>");
out.print("<body onload=\"autoSubmit();\">");
out.print("<form id=\"form1\" method=\"post\" name=\"form1\" action=\"url comes here\">");
out.print("</form>");
out.print("</body>");
out.print("</html>");
```

second submit

```
URL url = new URL(null, "url comes here", new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler());
HttpsURLConnection urlConn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

I want first one to be succeed in any case such as timeout exception of the second submit.

Comment: first submission should not wait until the second one to be completed,should work as two separated submits

Comment: Check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419022/submitting-multiple-forms-via-ajax-sync-or-async

This might help you !

Answer (score 0):

Submit two forms asynchronously using ajax.