# Laravel - multiple forms with one submit

Tags: database, laravel, forms, submit

I have two forms but it needs to submit on just one submit button. I do JS code for that but it only submit my last form `{!! Form::open(['action' => 'AdsController@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => 'f1', 'name' => 'f1', 'onsubmit' => 'return validate(this)']) !!}` and I don't know why?
Here is my full simple code:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'TestsController@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'id' => 'f2', 'name' => 'f2', 'onsubmit' => 'return validate(this)']) !!}

<!--
<form action="TestsController@store" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="f1" id="f1" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
-->
    <div class="column">
        <label for="title">Title:</label></br>
        <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <br>
    <input required type="file" class="form-control" name="images[]" placeholder="" multiple>
    <br><br>
<!--
</form>
-->

{!! Form::close() !!}


{!! Form::open(['action' => 'AdsController@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => 'f1', 'name' => 'f1', 'onsubmit' => 'return validate(this)']) !!}
    <input type="hidden" name="cars" value="1">
{!! Form::close() !!}


<button onclick="submitAll();" class="btn btn-primary">
    Submit
</button>

<script>
    'use strict';

    function validate(form){
        //forms processsing goes here...
        console.log(form, form.name)
        return false;
    }

    function submitAll(){
        for(var i=0, n=document.forms.length; i<n; i++){
            document.forms[i].submit();
        }

    }

</script>
```

So just my last form is submitted and I don't know why.. I need to submit all of them. Please help

Comment: You want to submit each form with an AJAX call, not `.submit()`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419022/submitting-multiple-forms-via-ajax-sync-or-async

Comment: All your forms are submitted. Imagine you can click very, very fast, and that in the space of a few milliseconds, you click every button on the page, from top to bottom. What will happen? Since they are not submitted via AJAX, they are full HTML form POSTs.  Only one of them can happen at one time, just like clicking 5 links very very quickly - your browser will not go to 5 pages, just the last one link you clicked, because that last click interrupted the navigation that was happening from the previous click. So the last form to be submitted is the one that actually completes being submitted.